# php adding amount in rows

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, addition

I want to add the rows that is being query in database. There is an amount paid, previous balance, new balance.. I want the previous balance to be added by paid amount.

```
Num|pay|old|new

1  |100|500|600

2  |120|600|720

3  |200|720|920

4  |300|720|920

5  |350|720|920

6  |500|720|920
```

The database query has data of amountPaid (pay), previous balance (old), new balance (new), but the data in column(new) is wrong.I want to correct it in `for`loop.Is there a way to help me in this? to get the column(new) value is 
`column(pay)100  + column(old)500 = column(new)600`.
the column(new) in number two will be put in `column(old)600` then added by `column(pay)120` is equal to `column(new)720` and so on.

Hope you can help me in this...

Comment: `update table_name set new = pay + old`

Answer (score 1):

**I suppose you are adding the amounts when user submits it**

1) Use mysql UPDATE clause in order to change the value in the coloumns

2) use while loop to get the previous value selecting it with a specific id which I suppose you have in your table

3) add it with a new value and update the new amount coloumn

**PHP**

```
<?php
     $id=$_POST['id'];
     $amount=$_POST['amount'];

    include("connection.php"); 
    $sql="SELECT * FROM  `tablename` WHERE  `user_id` ='$id'";
    $res=mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($res){


            $t2 = $row['previous_amount'];
            $t3=$t2+$amount;
            $sql="UPDATE  `bank`.`tablename` SET `new_amount' = '$t3'";
        }
?>
```

Comment: Yes but some data is already in the database and i want to fix it. is there a way to update all data in the database. The amount has specific id and person. i want the first payment which can be determined in the datepaid to be the start of update then next is so on.

Comment: " i want the first payment which can be determined in the datepaid to be the start of update then next is so on" what do you mean by that ??